# Book with a lake monster befriended by a possibly magic girl

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book I read ages ago. I don't remember the title or author but I remember the cover.

It featured a sad girl hugging her knees to her chest in the sand next to a lake. There's a little twig sculpture in the sand next to her. In the distance is a large figure. The cover was primarily blue.

From what I remember, the story was about a lonely girl who uses magic by stringing twigs together. I think she summons/befriends a giant lake creature.

Comment: I found _[Twig Stories](http://www.amazon.com/Leaf-Long-Ice-Twig-Stories/dp/1480080888/ref=pd_bxgy_14_img_z)_, a series of books by Jo Marshall. Only if that's it, you'd have a lot of details mixed up. Still, you never know.

Comment: Reading the title of this question, with its "possibly... maybe" construction, made it sound less like you're trying to identify a particular story and more like you're looking for a recommendation for a book to read this weekend. :)

Answer (score 10):

Only 3 years late, but I'm pretty sure this is the cover: Michael Whelan's *Periwinkle*, which according to his [art site](https://www.michaelwhelan.com/galleries/periwinkle/) was used for Patricia A. McKillip's [*The Changeling Sea*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/59.The_Changeling_Sea) (1988).

> From The Art of Michael Whelan:
>
> "Patricia A. McKillip is a terrific writer, very inspiring. My cover
>   concepts for her novel The Changeling Sea, taken together, were some
>   of the best I'd done up to that point. Chosing among them was
>   extremely difficult. When the editors asked, 'Well, which one do you
>   prefer?' I didn't know what to say. I liked them all. Then I pointed
>   out that other things being equal, the one with the largest face would
>   probably be the most attractive on the bookstands, so that decided the
>   issue."

[image: _Periwinkle_, girl sitting by a lake]

Comment: <sigh/> Sometimes I really miss the quality of the cover art that was produced in the 1980-90s.  Michael Whelan, Jim Burns, Tony Roberts, all the others...  Real art, not Photoshop pastiches!

Comment: Note:  [according to ISFDb](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?143342) that art was *only* ever used (in English) for *The Changeling Sea*.